# Salefoce implementation question validation rule with picklist

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

I have picklist field: 
his name is 
Color:
- Red
- Green
- Yellow 
***- Grey***

How do I make with validation rule: that it **will be impossible to select the grey color?**

Thanks
Liraz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF(ISPICKVAL(Color__c, "Grey"), true, false)

Comment: what should I insert instead of the true or false values?

Comment: What do you mean with insert? Nothing. If color = grey, the validation rule will fire, and your users will be blocked and see the error message you provided.